# Calculate Total Cost of Related Child Items

Tags: sharepoint-list

I originally built an InfoPath form with repeating tables for Employee Expenses, which works great, but this doesn't work on mobile. (We want to be able to use on mobile and take pictures of receipts). So I started over and I've built a Powerapp for employee expenses, and the data goes back to two SharePoint lists. One list is Expenses, which is the employee name, dates, status, etc.  The other list is LineItems, which is each expense detail, which is then a Related Items web part on the default display form for the Expenses list.

I have searched everywhere for a solution that will allow me to have a field in the Parent list (Expenses) that will show a grand total of all of the related expense items (Line Items list). I need this to be a field to trigger an email (using Microsoft Flow) in the event the Expense total is more than $1,000.